# How to run ROS metapackage

Tags: ros, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to built a metapackage (say "robot") which will contain all packages for the robot. Can metapackage directory contain the package files?
Moreover can I refer metapackage in rosrun e.g. rosrun metapackage node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261297/how-to-run-ros-metapackage/) by [dgangwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30302/dgangwar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can metapackage directory contain the package files?

No. Metapackages should be empty. See #q256493 for a discussion of what metapackages are used for.

> Moreover can I refer metapackage in rosrun e.g. rosrun metapackage node.

No. Metapackages do not contain any executable artefacts, so you cannot use them with `rosrun`.

See [REP-140 - Package Manifest Format Two Specification - Data Representation - <metapackage/>](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#metapackage) (also referenced in #q256493) for the normative text that defines what metapackages are, what their structure/layout/contents is and why they are used.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1